# bootstrap slider - get data-slider-min and data-slider-max values

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple issue for getting the max and min values of a bootstrap slider. I am a beginner about this.

Here's my code snippet

HTML :

```
<input id="slider1" type="hidden" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0.2" data-slider-max="9.8" data-slider-step="0.2" data-slider-value="[3.4,6.6]"/>
```

Javascript :

```
var slider= new Slider("#slider1");
slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
  console.log(slider.getValue());
  var min = slider.data("slider-min").getValue();
  var max = slider.data("slider-max").getValue();
  console.log(min);
  console.log(max);
  le1 = slideEvt[0] - min;
  le2 = slideEvt[1] - le1;
  le3 = max - le1 - le2;
});
```

but it doesn't work

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the slider `options` and read `min` and `max` value from it.

```
 var slider= new Slider("#slider1");
 slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
   var min = slider.options.min,
       max = slider.options.max
   ...
   ...
 });
```